# Struct data not printing

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, c-strings

For some reason the data I have added to my linked list is not printing.
It prints if I add the function `PrintList` right after adding or if I print it within a for loop with a set number but I want it to print after adding all the products and after breaking the while loop.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct SProducts
 {
    char *name;
    struct SProducts *next;  
 }Products; 

Products *Add(Products *list, char *file)
{
 Products *el = (Products *) malloc(sizeof(Products));
 if(el != NULL)
    {
      el->name = file;
      el->next = list;
    }
 return el;
}

void PrintList(Products *list)
{
   while(list != NULL)
   {
    printf("%s", list->name);
    list = list->next;
  }
}

int main(void){
    Products *list = NULL;
    char file[255];
    while (fgets(file,sizeof(file),stdin) != NULL)
    {
        list = Add(list, file);
        if (file[0] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    PrintList(list);
}
```

Comment: `el->name = file;` ==> `el->name = malloc(strlen(file) + 1); strcpy(el->name, file);` --- don't forget to `free()` the resources when you no longer need them.

Comment: BTW: make sure you `#include <stdlib.h>` and get rid of the cast to the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are always passing the same address of the first character of the local character array file.

```
list = Add(list, file);
```

So the last string that is stored in this array will be outputted for all nodes of the list.

You need to allocate dynamically a character array in each node that will store the passed string.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

Products * Add( Products *list, const char *file )
{
    Products *el =  malloc( sizeof( Products ) );

    if ( el != NULL )
    {
        e1->name = malloc( strlen( file ) + 1 );
        if ( e1->name != NULL ) strcpy( el->name, file );
        el->next = list;
    }

    return el;
}

//...

while ( fgets( file, sizeof( file ), stdin ) != NULL && file[0] != '\n' )
{
    file[ strcspn( file, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    Products *tmp = Add( list, file );
    if ( tmp != NULL ) list = tmp;
}
```

Pay attention to that you need also at least write a function that will delete all the allocated memory of the list when  it will not be required any more.